# Why does WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri) add a slash at the end of the URI?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I wrote a little code in c# in order to invoke a REST web service.
Without request body since all the parameters are part of the URL.

I build my URI like this :

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
uriBuilder.Host = "xxxx.yyyy.com"
uriBuilder.Host = uriBuilder.Host + queryString.ToString();
```

Then i create my HTTPWebRequest :

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.Uri);
```

The response of this request was empty...after debbuging i found that the code add a '/' on the last character of my URI and it's because of this slash i get no values...

Why my code add this slash ? How to avoid it please ( instead of doing a substring, of course, i would like to avoid dirty fixes).

Thanks a lot

Comment: At what point is it adding the trailing forward slash? Is it at the point of WebRequest.Create()?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `UriBuilder`'s [`Query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder.query?view=net-6.0) property to specify the query string

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder
{
    Host = "xxxx.yyyy.com",
    Query = queryString.ToString()
};
```

Then you use the `UriBuilder`'s build function which is the `ToString`:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriBuilder.ToString());
```

With this approach your URI will not have a trailing slash.